# Call notifyDataSetChanged() on adapter from menu

Tags: android, listview, refresh, adapter

I have an app that creates custom array adapter called StabelArrayAdapter which based on the ArrayAdapter class. It is created in the onCreate() method of the activity and I want to refresh it from a menu when the view changes. I can't access the adapter from the menu and I can't make it public.

How can I refresh the list view from a menu?

Greg

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listNames);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.list_add:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Add new list" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
                return true;
            case R.id.list_delete:
                //change data here
                final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListLists);

                //--> Cannot resolve symbol 'adapter'

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the adapter a class member and then you can reference it.

```
private StableArrayAdapter adapter;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listNames);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.list_add:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Add new list" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
            return true;
        case R.id.list_delete:
            //change data here
            final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListLists);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```